# Why does the backbone.js where function return an array of models?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

When I use the `Backbone.Collection.where` function to filter the collection I get an array of models as return value but not an other filtered collection object. So I can't use other collection functions with that.

What is the purpose of such behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`where` isn't the only method that returns an `Array`. `where` returns a new `Array` because you definitely don't want it mutating your existing `Collection` automatically. Also, many times you may want the result in `Array` form.

For whatever reason, the BB devs decided that it was better to return a new `Array` rather than a new `Collection`. One thought could be that, perhaps the returned data would be used in a different type of `Collection`. Another reason could be so that you always know what is returned from one of these methods. 2+ types of collections will ALWAYS return `Arrays` from these types of methods rather than having to try and inspect via `instanceof` or something else that isn't very reliable.

**Edit**

In addition, you COULD make your collections behave in a manner where you return new `Collections`. Create a base Collection to do something like this:

```
// Override the following methods
var override = ["where","find",...];
var collectionProto = Backbone.Collection.prototype;
BaseCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({});
for (var key in collectionProto) {
    if (collectionProto.hasOwnProperty(key) && override.indexOf(key) > -1) {
        BaseCollection.prototype[key] = function () {
            return new this.constructor(collectionProto[key].apply(this, arguments);
        };
    }
}
```

Instead over extending off Backbone.Collection, extend off BaseCollection.

Comment: I've added some extra context for making collections behave the way you might want them too.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can still use most of the underscore utilities on arrays. Here's how to use each() after a filter()

_.each( MyCollection.filter( filter_fn() {} ), each_fn() {} )